# MS Access to Google Earth Pro

Tags: shapefile, google-earth, kmz, ms-access

I am embarking on a new project and hoping for some pointers. I am reasonably tech savvy but definitely in the "advanced beginner" category for coding... but keen to test myself.

I am trying to find a way to integrate Google Earth Pro in to out Land Surveying database. Our MS Access 2007 database contains circa 2500 old jobs, each with fields representing the Lot, Block and Plan that they are contained within. (A Plan is made up of blocks, a Block made up of lots - each property in the city has, in the most part, a unique Lot/Block/Plan).

The local government has a data warehouse with downloadable KMZ/Shapefiles depicting all Lot/Block/Pans in the city, which can be imported in to Google Earth Pro.

I would like to create an access macro which, on inputting a new job, allows the user to view in Google Earth the new job while highlighting any old jobs within the same block and plan.

Would anyone be able to tell me a suitable method for conducting this. Workflow would be as follows:

1. New job entry in access including the property's Lot/Block/Plan
2. Access database searched for previous jobs in Block/Plan of above
   (Lots are unique)
3. Latest KMZ/Shapefile either manually or automatically downloaded
   from government data warehouse (these files change frequently so
   cannot have them saved locally) in to Google Earth Pro.
4. Lot/Block/Plan info from KMZ/Shapefile datatables cross-referenced
   with Access info.
5. All polygons in Blocks/Plan highlighted as normal, but Lots in
   common with old jobs highlighted in different colour

Can anyone recommend a program which can siphon out the Lot/Block/Plan details from Access and a KMZ or Shapefile, cross-reference them, and then display in Google Earth?

Comment: you might want to look at ArcGIS Explorer with the expansion pack to view spatial data (personal geodatabases which are access .mdb files) http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/2500//en/index.html you can add notes to the tables